# How to achieve 100% sizing for an img element that's inside of a full-screen fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a lightbox-like element. I handled the JavaScript code that takes the clicked image's src and puts it in myImage etc. but I just can't manage to have it 100% height. It always crosses the paddings that box2 sets on bottom.

It works when I don't put the button, so it seems like I'm doing something wrong with it, maybe? I still need the button so this is the least amount of elements I need. IDK if it would work but just taking box2 out wouldn't solve it because I need the content width to be a maximum of 1200px.

I tried this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: black;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;    
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: none;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: start;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 80px;
  padding: 120px 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.myImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <button></button>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="myImage">
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: this is my first post! Hello world!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `img` cannot take 100% of height since the `.box2` also contains a `button` which already takes some of that 100% of height.

If making a different layout is not an option, the absolute positioning of a `button` can be used so its presence can be "ignored" by the image. Run this code snippet and then press the "Full page" to see how it would look like:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: black;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: start;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 80px;
  padding: 120px 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <button></button>
    <img src="" class="myImage">
  </div>
</div>
```

The button can also be moved up to not overlap the image:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: black;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: start;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 80px;
  padding: 120px 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <button></button>
    <img src="" class="myImage">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get  it, and I used your solution. But why doesn't the img just take whatever's left from box2's height?

Comment: Because there is a `gap: 80px;` in `.box2` - this space is added between the child elements. Remove it (or change to `gap: 0;`), then remove `position: absolute; margin-top: -40px;` from the `button` and the image will take what's left: *100% - button height*.